# Admin page shows only one model field of many

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class items(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField(),
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100),
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

When i try to insert a data on admin page it is showing only `category` field and I'm can fill only this one field.

Also it is showing an extra `s` in table names for no reason.

I am expecting that there should be 3 columns to fill data: `name`, `price` and `category` but getting only one of them.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk2Fx.png]

Comment: Make sure you are doing the migration right.

Comment: Your `items` class should be named `Item` (singular, and captalized per convention).

Comment: Because you added commas to the `price` and `name` attribute definitions, you inadvertently changed them from something derived from `django.db.models.Field` to a Python tuple. Hence they are no longer viewed by Django as fields, and hence they're excluded from the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No comma needed, try this:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class items(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And do not foget to make migrations:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```